# Flutter: I am uploading a file to database using post api. But it gives me a bug

Tags: flutter, api, dart, mobile

I am using file picker to pick the file. The file can be png jpg or pdf.

```
                          FilePickerResult? result =
                          await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
                        type: FileType.custom,
                        allowMultiple: true,
                        allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'pdf'],
                        allowCompression: true,
                      );
                      setState(() {
                        if (result!.files.length != 0) {
                          _con!.thumbnail = result.files;
                        }
                      });
```

And the following is the code for uploading it to the database using post api using Dio library

```
  Future uploadFile(BuildContext context) async {
setState(() {
  isFormLoading = true;
});
var R;

Dio D = Dio();
D.options.headers = {
  'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
  // 'Content-type': 'application/json',
  'Accept': 'application/json',
};

FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
  "image": DD.MultipartFile.fromFile(thumbnail.elementAt(0).path!),
});

R = await D.post(BASE_URL + "api/v2/upload/21", data: formData);

dynamic Response = R.data;

print('Response is >>>>>>');
print(R);

// BotToast.showText(text: Response["success"].toString());

setState(() {
  isFormLoading = false;
});
```

}

Comment: what's the bug? can you post here?

Comment: Without bug we can't help you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

modify the extension of the upload file file (jpg, png, pdf)

var formData = FormData.fromMap({

```
      "file":

          await MultipartFile.fromFile(path, filename: 'upload.jpg'),
      
    });
    Response response = await dio.post(
          Constant().urlBase + Constant().confirm_package_reception,
          data: formData);`enter code here`
```